# Efficient double for loop where range of second loop depends on value of first

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, python-itertools

Is there a quicker way (perhaps using `itertools`) to implement the code below?

```
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        do stuff
    do stuff
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to iterate through two lists at once and verify each list value on same position?

Comment: I don't really understand either of the above questions. Sorry. But I want to be able to do stuff in the first loop separate to the j loop, if that makes sense. I'll update the question.

Comment: What is "do stuff"? I don't think there's anything wrong with your approach or anything to achieve by using `itertools`

Comment: I was about to recommend the zip method, but what you seek is already in your hands I believe.

Comment: Do you mind if we count down instead of up?

Comment: yes counting down is okay for me

Comment: You can't optimise this code much if you need all of the iterations.

Comment: I just noticed that you modified the question so that you need to do stuff in the outer loop as well as in the inner loop. And in that case, there's no point trying to do anything clever with itertools: any slight savings would be offset by having to do an `if` test on _every_ iteration.

Comment: thank you for your comments

Comment: Otherwise, you could have done this: `for i, j in combinations(range(4, -1, -1), 2): print(i-1, j)`

Answer (score 3):

You are generating *combinations with replacement*, so [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) can generate these for you, albeit with `j` and `i` reversed:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

for j, i in combinations_with_replacement(range(10), 2):
    # ...
```

Note the inversion of `j` and `i`; this produces the same *pairs of values* as your nested loop, just in a different order:

```
>>> sorted(combinations_with_replacement(range(10), 2)) == sorted((j, i) for i in range(10) for j in range(i + 1))
True
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that the OP now has to do stuff in both the inner loop and the outer loop.

Comment: @PM2Ring: it depends on what the OP wants to do for each distinct `i` value though, if that matters. You can always use different means to track if your `i` value has already been seen (such as sets or dictionaries).

Comment: Well, sure, but you still have to do that test on every iteration. And IMHO merely reversing the output order isn't as drastic as the funky order that `combinations_with_replacement` yields. :) But I guess it depends on the application.

Comment: In the first `do stuff`, I am setting index i,j of one numpy array to a value. In the second `do stuff` I am setting index i of a different numpy array.

Comment: @PM2Ring: it's not that funky an order, and again, it depends on the exact use case if the order actually matters!

Comment: The order makes sense, it just looks a bit weird because we swapped `i` and `j`. And it seems that the order doesn't matter. OTOH, the OP should've mentioned that this is for Numpy...

Comment: @Jack You really should've tagged this with Numpy. Generally, we try to avoid doing Python `for` loops with Numpy, since it can do various looping things at C speed. But it's a bit late to change your question, now that it has an answer. Maybe ask a new question with a little more context so we aren't trying to solve an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Jack In the mean time, you can simply do the `i` loop and the `i,j` loops separately, using a simple `for` loop  for the `i` stuff, and either Martijn's or my solution for the `i,j` loop. That way you don't need to do the testing I was talking about earlier. But it's probably easier just to use the loops you posted in the question. :)